# webpage test with python selenium: really slow execution

Tags: python, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote, in Python, using Selenium, a very simple test of a webpage

Here the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
    # cose da fare prima dei test
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()  # Opera? credo sia usabile :D

    def tearDown(self):
    # cose da fare dopo dei test
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_yahoo(self):
        # browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
        pagina = "http://ricordandoti.net/it/app-per-scoprire-il-cimitero-del-poblenou/"
        self.browser.get(pagina)      # Load page
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)    # aspetto si carichi tutta la pagina
                                           # forzando di aspettare 3 s
        assert "Ricordandoti" in self.browser.title


if __name__ == '__main__':  # 7    
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

It works, but it takes almost a minute to be executed:

```
> Running: /home/.../tests/functional_tests_ricord.py (Wed Jan 21 13:32:05 2015)
> 
> .
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 1 test in 60.798s
> 
> OK
```

I use ninja IDE to write the code (in a Ubuntu 14.04 machine).
This seems to be the reason.

Executing code directly from shell, it takes 20 s:

```
> subu@VR46-U:~$ python3 "/home/.../tests/functional_tests_ricord.py"
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 20.865s

OK
```

What can I do to fast up the execution?

Comment: what about waiting 5 second with the implicit wait command ? You can start by using an explicit wait command (see http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html)

Answer (score 1):

The following should speed things up for you:

- upgrade `selenium` to the latest version (currently `2.44.0`)

  ```
  pip3 install selenium --upgrade
  ```
- upgrade `firefox` to  the latest version (currently `35.0`)

It was slower on my end before the upgrades, now it is:

```
$ python3 test.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 6.258s

OK
```

Comment: May be is as you say. Unfortunatly I can't update selenium the way you suggest.