# Python Selenium Headless Error: Element not Interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I was making a program which scrapes info about stocks from the website https://www.tradingview.com/screener/ which used selenium.here is the code:

```py
def stock(aaa):
    a=[]
    chrome_options = Options()
    custom_header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={custom_header}")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
   
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    browser.get("https://www.tradingview.com/screener/")
    entry=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-data-table-sticky-wrapper.tv-screener-sticky-header-wrapper > table > thead > tr > th.tv-data-table__th.tv-data-table__cell.js-tv-data-table-th.js-tv-data-table-th-name.tv-data-table__sortable.tv-screener-table__sortable.tv-screener-table__th.js-draggable > div > div > div.tv-screener-table__search-query.js-search-query.tv-screener-table__search-query--without-description>input")
    entry.send_keys(aaa)
```

It was working well when it was not in headless mode,but when I switched to headless,it gave this error code:

```
File "c:\Users\██████\cowination.py", line 181, in <module>
    aaa=stock("zydus")
  File "c:\Users\██████\cowination.py", line 20, in stock
    entry.send_keys(aaa)
  File "C:\Users\████████████\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\████████████\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\████████████\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\████████████\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

At first I thought it was because the window was not maximized as the entry box is not visible when not maximized.So I added the `--start-maximized` argument,but it too didn't work.I tried even Webdriverwait,but that to didn't work. So is there any way  I can solve this problem?
thanks in advance

Edit:
I have written my code according to the correct answer.here is the code:
from selenium import webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
def stock(aaa):
    a=[]
    chrome_options = Options()
    custom_header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={custom_header}")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
   
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    browser.get("https://www.tradingview.com/screener/")
    browser.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(3)
    e=browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[8]/div[1]/img")
    e.click()
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener-toolbar.tv-screener-toolbar--standalone.tv-screener-toolbar--standalone_sticky > div.tv-screener-market-select.tv-dropdown.tv-dropdown--inline.tv-dropdown-behavior.i-opened > div.tv-dropdown__body.tv-dropdown-behavior__body.tv-dropdown__body--over-trigger.tv-dropdown__body--position_right.undefined.i-opened > div > div.tv-dropdown-behavior__inscroll.js-content > div:nth-child(19) > div > span')).perform()
    india=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener-toolbar.tv-screener-toolbar--standalone.tv-screener-toolbar--standalone_sticky > div.tv-screener-market-select.tv-dropdown.tv-dropdown--inline.tv-dropdown-behavior.i-opened > div.tv-dropdown__body.tv-dropdown-behavior__body.tv-dropdown__body--over-trigger.tv-dropdown__body--position_right.undefined.i-opened > div > div.tv-dropdown-behavior__inscroll.js-content > div:nth-child(19) > div > span')
    india.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    filters=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener-toolbar.tv-screener-toolbar--standalone.tv-screener-toolbar--standalone_sticky > div.tv-screener-toolbar__button.tv-screener-toolbar__button--options.tv-screener-toolbar__button--filters.apply-common-tooltip.common-tooltip-fixed")
    filters.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    reset=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#overlap-manager-root > div > div > div > div.tv-screener-search.js-screener-search > div")
    reset.click()
    exitbut=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#overlap-manager-root > div > div > div > div.tv-dialog__section.tv-dialog__section--title.tv-tabbed-dialog__header.js-close-button-place > div.tv-dialog__close.js-dialog__close.tv-tabbed-dialog__close")
    exitbut.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    entry=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-data-table-sticky-wrapper.tv-screener-sticky-header-wrapper > table > thead > tr > th.tv-data-table__th.tv-data-table__cell.js-tv-data-table-th.js-tv-data-table-th-name.tv-data-table__sortable.tv-screener-table__sortable.tv-screener-table__th.js-draggable > div > div > div.tv-screener-table__search-query.js-search-query.tv-screener-table__search-query--without-description>input")
    
    browser.execute_script("$('.tv-screener-table__search-input.js-search-input').val('{}');".format(aaa))
    action = webdriver.ActionChains(browser);
    action.send_keys(Keys.RETURN).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).perform()
    time.sleep(6)
    p=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.tv-data-table__cell.apply-common-tooltip.tv-screener-table__cell.tv-screener-table__cell--left.tv-screener-table__cell--with-marker > div > div:nth-child(3) > span.tv-screener__description")
    p1=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > span")
    a.append(p.text)
    a.append(p1.text)
    p2=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(3)")
    p3=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(4)")
    a.append(p2.text)
    a.append(p3.text)
    p4=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(5) > span")
    a.append(p4.text)
    p5=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(6)")
    a.append(p5.text)
    p6=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(7)")
    a.append(p6.text)
    p7=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(8)")
    a.append(p7.text)
    p8=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(9)")
    a.append(p8.text)

    p10=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#js-screener-container > div.tv-screener__content-pane > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(11)")
    a.append(p10.text)
    return f"""Name of stock:{a[0]}
    Last price:{a[1]}
    Change %:{a[2]}
    Change value:{a[3]}
    Rating:{a[4]}
    Volume:{a[5]}
    Market Cap:{a[6]}
    Price to Earning Ratio:{a[7]}
    EPS(TTM):{a[8]}
    Sector:{a[9]}
    """
```

here is the output :

```
Name of stock:RELIANCE INDUSTRIES LTD.
    Last price:2000.90
    Change %:0.79%
    Change value:15.60
    Rating:Buy
    Volume:210.603K
    Market Cap:12.656T
    Price to Earning Ratio:—
    EPS(TTM):—
    Sector:Energy Minerals
```

this is the expected output:

```
Name of stock:ZYDUS WELLNESS LTD.
        Last price:2110.15
        Change %:-0.57%
        Change value:-12.15
        Rating:Buy
        Volume:24.03K
        Market Cap:134.251B
        Price to Earning Ratio:114.58
        EPS(TTM):18.52
        Sector:Consumer Non-Durables
```

Now it is typing in the search box but giving wrong output which is actually the info of the stock at the homepage and not that of the search results .
Can anyone tell why it is happening?

Comment: Side note: is  `stock`  returning nothing a typo ?

Comment: Actually it would return some info about the stock that was searched but I gave only the part of the code that was raising the error as the other code was very lenghty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `headless` mode the `send_keys` won't work in this case.
See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632828/selenium-with-python-send-keys-doesnt-work-on-headless-ubuntu).
When you remove `headless` option and replace the "zydus" with e.g. "aapl" everything works fine.

One ways to work this around in your specific case would be e.g.:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser.execute_script("$('.tv-screener-table__search-input.js-search-input').val('{}');".format(aaa))
action = webdriver.ActionChains(browser);
action.send_keys(Keys.SPACE).send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).perform()
```

This works exactly the same way as `entry.send_keys(aaa)`

Comment: So is there any alternative for send_keys?

Comment: now the thing is it is entering the search into the input but it seems to not return the results

Comment: This is a different question which does't fit anymore into the original post. To ask a new question make a new post: one question per post.