# Selenuim+Python get the URL of a clickable element that doesn't have href

Tags: python, selenium, hyperlink, webdriver

I have an element in my WebPage and this element has no "href" in its HTML code, but the element is clickable and drives to another page, so what I want to do is to open the page in a new window or tab. When I use the `key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(element).key_up(Key.CONTROL).perform()`

this just opens the new page in the same window (btw even manually performed, this is same). So even right-click (context menu) doesn't contain the open in new Tab/Window. 
Is there any possible way to get the URL to where this element drives so that I can open a new window and paste it there, or just open the new page in a new window or tab?

Here is the css code of the Element:

```
<tr class="ng-scope element-active" ng-if="$data.length" ng-click="$ctrl.open(element)" ng-repeat="element in $data" ng-class="[{ disabled: element.elementStatus == '2' }, 'element-' + element.status.toLowerCase()]">
```

Comment: Can you share the URL if it is a public one? Thanks

Comment: So you simply want to open your elment (which I assume has a DOM identifier?) in a new tab? Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python

Comment: @DebanjanB it's not a public URL but here is how the element looks like in the page `<tr class="ng-scope element-active" ng-if="$data.length" ng-click="$ctrl.open(element)" ng-repeat="element in $data" ng-class="[{ disabled: element.elementStatus == '2' }, 'element-' + element.status.toLowerCase()]">`
@MedAli yes I did but this works when you already know the URL you want to access to, which is what I want to get.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add any relevant information. And as I suggested in chat, read [ask] and [mcve] to make sure your question is answerable.

Comment: If manually clicking the WebElement opens the new page in the same window, why are you trying to do things differently through Automation? Thanks

Comment: Because at some time I need to get back to the previous page where the main test is running and find out that all the already set elements became stale (resetting them takes long time in the test procedure)

Comment: @AnasBouayed As per the `Business Requirement` if the `Production Environment Deployment Code` is configured in such a way that the new page needs to open in the current window/tab, as per Best Testing Practice you must not try to tamper the usual/default behavior of the system. Tampering with the usual/default behavior may result into unexpected system behavior which may make your Test Execution unreliable. Thanks