# Selenium switch focus to tab, which opened after clicking link

Tags: java, selenium, tabs, focus

For automation purposes, I am working on creating a script that finds a row in a table. This row is clickable and opens a new tab/adress.

With selenium, I am now able to find the table row, click on the link, and the new tab opens. The problem is that I can't find any way to switch the focus to the newly opened tab. I tried to get all windowHandles and see if I could switch, but even after the new tab has opened, there is only 1 windowHandle.

Below is my code:

```
WebElement tableRow=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", tableRow);

ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
```

The Arraylist always contains 1 single windowHandle, not 2. So I am not able to switch focus to the new tab. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

To properly switch to the newly opened *Tab* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *New Tab* to render and then through a `for()` loop you need to iterate through the available *WindowHandles* and invoke `switchTo().window()` with the *WindowHandle* which is not the previous TAB through the following code block :

```
String first_handle = driver.getWindowHandle();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", tableRow);
new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String winHandle:allHandles)
{
    if (!first_handle.equalsIgnoreCase(winHandle)
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ryan Glad that you have brought up. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-and-iterate-through-tabs-and-windows-using-windowhandles/46346324#46346324) discussion I have explained in details why Simon says `While the datatype used for storing the list of handles may be ordered by insertion, the order in which the WebDriver implementation iterates over the window handles to insert them has no requirement to be stable. The ordering is arbitrary`. So I would avoid the index by all possible means.

Comment: I see. Does this apply even if there are only 2 possible tabs to choose from?

Comment: @Ryan I would prefer to be as generic as possible no matter how many windows/tabs 2, 3, 4 .... are present

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just have to wait until a second window is created? Maybe selenium checks window handles too fast?

Try with `WebDriverWait`

Example:

```
String currentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));

Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for (String handle : allHandles) {
    if (!handle.equals(currentHandle)) driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}
```

If a number of windows will be less or more than 2, `TimeoutException` will occur.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me, waited until the number of windows became 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
 **Try this code:**

   public static void switchToNewWindow(WebDriver driver, WebElement 
   causeOfNewWindow) {

    // Get Handles before opening new window
    Set<String> oldHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    // Click element to open new Window
    causeOfNewWindow.click();

    // Get Handles after opening new window
    Set<String> newHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for (String handle : newHandles) {

        if (!oldHandles.contains(handle)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        }

    }
}
```