# Selenium webdriver not finding add to cart button in Amazon

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, selenium-chromedriver, pageobjects

After selecting a product and opening it in another page Im not able to click on add to cart button in amazon using selenium.

Comment: What is the Page URL ? Where you are stuck exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not switching to other page, `Add to card` option will not be located.
Switch to the opened page and then try to click on the button.

```
handles = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
driver.find_element_by_id("add-to-cart-button").click()
```

If you have done this, share the code you have tried and error you get.

Comment: What do you mean by `If you are not switching to other page` ?

Comment: @cruisepandey - When a product is clicked in amazon, the product details opens up in a new window. And Option for "Add to cart" will in the 2nd window.

Comment: No, I don't think so, at least not for me.  that's why we need more details from OP instead of just giving random answers.

Comment: And my random answer has this too. `If you have done this, share the code you have tried and error you get.`

Comment: you have more than 75 reputation, that could have been a comment.

Comment: refer to my code here please and please help me with this.                                                
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUhyl.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI9Ph.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/olyCc.png

Comment: How do we write code for window handles if we are using baseclass? Also Iam using Pojo class for finding element.Iam using cucumber bdd for writing feature file

Comment: @AparnaMurali - I am not proficient in JAVA, but you need incorporate a function in Baseclass to switch the windows. Refer the link. [Window handle question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59291995/16452840) and also there is another answer in JAVA which is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes got it.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Without HTML page you are trying to perform, it is difficult to pinpoint exactly. However, I would like to take a stab at it considering these:

1. Click on product in home page
2. Product opens in a new tab window
3. Click on add to cart

**P.S:** I will write it using Java since you haven't mentioned on the language being used. Will be similar in others as well

**Click on product in home page**

```
List <Webelement> productCheck = driver.findElements(By.xpath("<xpath of the product>"))
if (productCheck.size() == 0){
// do something
else {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath of the product>")).click();
}
```

**Product opens in a new tab window** and  **Click on add to cart**

```
String parent = driver.getWindowHandle();
List<String> windows = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(windows.get(1));

// Inside the tab window

List <WebElement> addtoCartButton = driver.findElements(By.xpath("<xpath of Add to cart button>"));
if (addtoCartButton.size() == 0 ) {
// do something
else {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("<xpath of Add to cart button>")).click();
}


// do whatever you want in the new tab and if you want to switch back then:

driver.switchTo().window(parent);
```

Comment: Yes got it Thank u so much