# How to click on the href tag?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, xpath, automated-tests

I have DOM

```
<div class="" data-zone-data="{"id":"97017425"}"data-zone-name="category-link">
<div class="_35SYu _1vnug" data-tid="acbe4a11 f8542ee1">
<a href="/catalog--kompiuternaia-tekhnika/54425" class="_3Lwc_">
<span class="_3z8Gf">Компьютеры</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
enter code here
```

Constructor:

```
   public YandexBeforeSearch(WebDriver driver, String search){
        this.driver = driver;
        this.driver.get("https://yandex.ru/search?text=" + search);

    }
```

My methods:

```
    public void clickToSite(){
        LinkYandexMarket = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@accesskey='1']"));
        LinkYandexMarket.click();
    }
    public void clickTYandexPC(){
        LinkYandexPC = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/catalog--kompiuternaia-tekhnika/54425']"));
        LinkYandexPC.click();
    }
```

My test:

```
@Test
public void testOpen(){
    YandexBeforeSearch yandexBeforeSearch = new YandexBeforeSearch(chromeDriver, "yandex market");
    yandexBeforeSearch.clickToSite();
    yandexBeforeSearch.clickTYandexPC();
}
```

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='catalog--kompiuternaia-tekhnika/54425']"}
```

I also used other attributes. The problem occurs only with this site. I can't follow the link to the category.

Comment: Error seems pretty clear? There is no element to be found, because your `<a>` has an href `"/catalog--kompiuternaia-tekhnika/54425"`, starting with `/`, and your xpath isn't actually looking for the same string, lacking the initial `/`.

Comment: Thank you I fixed it

Comment: then you probably want to delete this question again

Comment: is this question resolved?

Comment: no, but I realized that I open new windows and do not go to tabs, and I need to go to the href tab, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the 1st link `//a[@accesskey='1']` is clicked a new window is opened.

We need to switch to that new window to click on `//a[@href='/catalog--kompiuternaia-tekhnika/54425']`

```
// Click on the 1st link.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@accesskey='1']")).click();

// Get parent window.
String parentwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

// Get all window handles.
Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
List<String> windows1 = new ArrayList<>(windows);

// Switch to the new window to click on the other link.
driver.switchTo().window(windows1.get(1));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/catalog--kompiuternaia-tekhnika/54425']")).click();

// Switch back to parent window, if required.
driver.switchTo().window(parentwindow);
```

Comment: thank you very much, this code works, but as a beginner it is not particularly clear to me, do you have any guides for a detailed study?

Comment: Well there are so many tutorials about Selenium. You could refer these links as of now.[Link1](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/handle-multiple-windows-in-selenium), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59291995/16452840).