# Wait for window to open before attempting to switch to it

Tags: java, selenium, testing, ui-testing

Im having an issue with my tests where I select a button and then switch to the windwo that opens after i select the button, the issue is having is that i keep getting no frame exceptions and Out of bounds exception.

My code is:

```
        clickWithActions(driver, launchNote);
        sleepForTime(6000);
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();

        List list = Arrays.asList(handles.toArray());
        driver.switchTo().window(list.get(1).toString());
        sleepForTime(6000);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));

        break;
```

Is there any way that i can wait for this window to appear first with out long waits?

Answer (score 2):

There is this [`numberOfWindowsToBe()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe(int)) expected wait condition that sounds fitting here:

```
clickWithActions(driver, launchNote);

// wait for the number of windows to increase
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Before performing `clickWithActions()` you need to collect the initial *WindowHandle* and once you perform click you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for [`numberOfWindowsToBe(2)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe(int)). So your effective code block will be:

```
String first_handle = driver.getWindowHandle();
clickWithActions(driver, launchNote);
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
Set<String> allHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
for(String winHandle:allHandles)
{
    if (!first_handle.equalsIgnoreCase(winHandle)
    {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
}
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium switch focus to tab, which opened after clicking link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031048/selenium-switch-focus-to-tab-which-opened-after-clicking-link/49031245#49031245)
- [Best way to keep track and iterate through tabs and windows using WindowHandles using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-of-windows-with-selenium-in-ie11/46346324#46346324)