# java.util.NoSuchElementException in iterator method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception, window-handles

I am relatively new to coding.

Below is the code for my program which opens a windows(flipkart.com)> proceeds to the secondary window by clicking an icon inside the web-page. Now I want to generate the window handles for both first and second page but it gives me errors as given below

Programs:

```
package MoinPrograms;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class MouseOverActions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("// button [@class=\"_2AkmmA _29YdH8\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p [@class=\"_1AuloC\"and text()= \"Mobiles & Tablets\"]")).click();
        Set<String> FlipKart = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> k = FlipKart.iterator();
        String handle1 = k.next();
        String handle2 = k.next();
        System.out.println(handle1);
        System.out.println(handle2);
    }

}
```

Errors :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at MoinPrograms.MouseOverActions.main(MouseOverActions.java:24)
```

Comment: How are you dealing with the login pop-up when you first go to the page?  It could be that your code cannot find the elements because it is first being presented with a login pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while`-loop to make sure to get all elements:

```
Iterator<String> k = FlipKart.iterator();
while (k.hasNext()) {
        String handle = k.next();
        System.out.println(handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check yout list to make sure it has an element by using hasNext() method.

```
package MoinPrograms;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class MouseOverActions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("// button [@class=\"_2AkmmA _29YdH8\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p [@class=\"_1AuloC\"and text()= \"Mobiles & Tablets\"]")).click();
        Set<String> FlipKart = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> k = FlipKart.iterator();
        while(k.hasNext()){
          String handle1 = k.next();
          System.out.println(handle1);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one handle available in your code :

You can get it by using this code :

```
ArrayList<String> flipkart = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles()); 
        Iterator<String> k = flipkart.iterator();
        while (k.hasNext()) {
                String handle = k.next();
                System.out.println(handle);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### java.util.nosuchelementexception

As per the *Java Docs* of [**`java.util.nosuchelementexception`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) is thrown by various accessor methods to indicate that the element being requested does not exist.

Now if you look at the *Java Docs* of [**`next()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--) method it clearly mentions **next()** method returns the next element in the iteration or *NoSuchElementException* if the iteration has no more elements.

### Root Cause of the issue

In your use case, the root cause of **`java.util.nosuchelementexception`** is as follows :

- The `next()` method fails to return any element as per `MouseOverActions.java:24` in your code :

  ```
  String handle2 = k.next();
  ```

### Explaination

Before and after clicking on the element identified as `By.xpath("//p [@class=\"_1AuloC\"and text()= \"Mobiles & Tablets\"]")` there is only one *Window Handle* and `String handle1` is assigned with the *Window Handle*. As there is no second *Window Handle* available `String handle2 = k.next();` raises `java.util.nosuchelementexception`.

### Solution

You need to make the following tweaks to your own code :

- Remove the line of code :

  ```
  String handle2 = k.next();
  ```
- Remove the line of code :

  ```
  System.out.println(handle2);
  ```
- As *Firefox Browser* opens in maximized mode you don't need to `maximize` it further, so remove the line :

  ```
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  ```
- Update the *Selenium Java Client* to **v3.12.0** and use the following **JVM** property inconjunction with **GeckoDriver** :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  ```
- Your own code block to print the *Window Handle* is as follows :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("// button [@class=\"_2AkmmA _29YdH8\"]")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p [@class=\"_1AuloC\"and text()= \"Mobiles & Tablets\"]")).click();
  Set<String> FlipKart = driver.getWindowHandles();
  Iterator<String> k = FlipKart.iterator();
  String handle1 = k.next();
  System.out.println(handle1);
  ```
- Console Output :

  ```
  4294967297
  ```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**`Best way to keep track of Windows with Selenium in IE11?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-of-windows-with-selenium-in-ie11/46346324#46346324)