# Get URL for opened tab Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, cucumber

What I'm tesintg:
Go to webpage, click on a link which opens in a new tab. Confirm the URL for the new tab.

I'm doing this in Cucumber/Selenium/Java.

This is my Gherkin

```
Scenario Outline: The HomePage tourism box links to the correct page

Given I navigate to the HomePage in <language>
When I click on the visit Tourism PEI Button
Then I am taken to the Tourism PEI landing page URL in a new tab

Examples:
  | language |
  | English  |
  | French   |
```

Code I have for clicking the link:

```
 @When("^I click on the Visit\\s" + pageElements + "$")
public void iClickFOnTheVisitTourismPEIButton(String element)  {
    pageModel.pageObject(element).click();
    progressObj.wait(1);
}
```

And code I have tried to get the URL from the new tab. I'm struggling here. Everything I try opens a new tab, then the screen goes blank and says data; in the URL or it will open a new tab on top of the one that already does. I know I'm not really on the right track here. This is just the last thing I have tried.

```
@Then("^I am\\s*((?:not)?)\\staken to the Tourism PEI landing page URL in a new tab$")
public void iAmTakenToTheTourismPEILandingPageURLInANewTab() {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
}
```

I also tried this

```
 String currentURL;

       currentURL = driver.getWebDriver().getCurrentUrl();
       if (currentURL.equalsIgnoreCase("https://www.tourismpei.com/")) {
           System.out.println("Matches" + currentURL);
       } else {
           System.out.println("Does not match" + currentURL);
       }
```

It's taking the original URL and not the new tab...

Answer (score 9):

```
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    System.out.println(String.format("handle: %s, url: %s", handle, driver.getWebDriver().getCurrentUrl()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you invoke `click()` on the link which opens the URL in a *New Tab* you need to save/store the *WindowHandle* of the parent *Tab*:

```
//Declare as global variables
String parent_tab;
String child_tab;
// your other code work
@When("^I click on the Visit\\s" + pageElements + "$")
public void iClickFOnTheVisitTourismPEIButton(String element)  {
    parent_tab = driver.getWindowHandle();
    pageModel.pageObject(element).click();
}
```

Once you have invoked the `click()` next to extract the URL from the *New Tab* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for both `numberOfWindowsToBe()` **2** and `urlContains()` as follows:

```
@Then("^I am\\s*((?:not)?)\\staken to the Tourism PEI landing page URL in a new tab$")
public void iAmTakenToTheTourismPEILandingPageURLInANewTab() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
    Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> i1 = s1.iterator();
    while(i1.hasNext())
    {
        child_tab = i1.next();
        if (!parent_tab.equalsIgnoreCase(child_tab))
        {
        driver.switchTo().window(child_tab);
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("tourismpei.com"));
        String currentURL;
        currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        if (currentURL.equalsIgnoreCase("https://www.tourismpei.com/")) {
            System.out.println("Matches" + currentURL);
        } else {
        System.out.println("Does not match" + currentURL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note A** : As you have used `driver.getWebDriver()` as in `driver.getWebDriver().getCurrentUrl();` you may have to replace all the instances of `driver.*` with `driver.getWebDriver().*`

**Note B** : While you compare the *currentURL* with the sample *url* instead of using `currentURL.equalsIgnoreCase("https://www.tourismpei.com/")` you may use `currentURL.contains("https://www.tourismpei.com/")` for a linient match.

Here you will find a detailed discussion on [**Best way to keep track of Windows with Selenium in IE11?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-of-windows-with-selenium-in-ie11/46346324#46346324)