# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string while window handling with Selenium and Java in Linux

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, window-handles

I have an requirement of running test cases in CI pipeline. where the VM is linux. Selenium multiple window handling - `switchTo()` method throws exception for linux platform.

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string
```

Code trials:

```
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
```

Its declared as per multiple window handle way:

```
String subWindowHandler = null; 
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext()) { 
    subWindowHandler = iterator.next(); 
}
```

This code works perfectly in local windows system.

Comment: How is _subWindowHandler_ declared/defined?

Comment: its declared as per multiple window handle way -                                                              String subWindowHandler = null;
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
 subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}                                                                                                                                 This code works perfectly in local windows system

Comment: _multiple_ ? you mean _list_ of `windowHandles`?

Comment: @DebanjanB .. please check the above edited comment to answer your question

Comment: _Chrome_ / _ChromeDriver_ version please?

Comment: this exception I am getting on Gitlab CI pipeline. where it using  chromedriverVersion=79.0.3945.36 and Linux runner.                                                If I run the same code on local windows system. It runs perfect as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string
```

...implies that the **handle** which was passed as an argument needs to be a string.

Logically you are pretty close. Possibly the `driver.getWindowHandles()` is getting executed too early even before the second window handle is getting created/recognized.

---

### Solution

As a solution you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for `numberOfWindowsToBe(2)` and you can use the following code block:

```
String mainWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // store mainWindowHandler for future references
//line of code that opens a new TAB / Window
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));  //induce WebDriverWait
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext()) 
{ 
    String subWindowHandler = iterator.next(); 
    if (!mainWindowHandler.equalsIgnoreCase(subWindowHandler))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
    }
}
```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Best way to keep track and iterate through tabs and windows using WindowHandles using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-and-iterate-through-tabs-and-windows-using-windowhandles/46346324#46346324)