# How to handle new window, which opened automatically in new tab?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriverwait, window-handles, expected-condition

My test code do thomething, then automatically opening new tab and in a new tab automatically opening new window (not a tab).

When I use this code: `driver.getWindowHandles()` it is returns 2 tab ID instead 3 tab ID.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a new window to count the number of *WindowHandles* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for `numberOfWindowsToBe(2)` and you can use the following code block:

```
String mainWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // store mainWindowHandler for future references
//line of code that opens a new TAB / Window
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));  //induce WebDriverWait
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator(); 
while (iterator.hasNext()) 
{ 
    String subWindowHandler = iterator.next(); 
    if (!mainWindowHandler.equalsIgnoreCase(subWindowHandler))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
    }
}
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium switch focus to tab, which opened after clicking link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031048/selenium-switch-focus-to-tab-which-opened-after-clicking-link/49031245#49031245)
- [Best way to keep track and iterate through tabs and windows using WindowHandles using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-and-iterate-through-tabs-and-windows-using-windowhandles/46346324#46346324)
- [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: 'handle' must be a string while window handling with Selenium and Java in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521551/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-invalid-argument-handle-must-be-a-str/59522826#59522826)

Comment: Nice, thanks, it was problem to wait for 3 window... `new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(3));`. Works fine!