# How to close the browser and launch the browser again using selenium with python? Can you give sample code for this?

Tags: selenium

The below code throwing error.it's suceessfuflly closed but unable to launch the browser again.

```
driver.close()
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Comment: are there other windows opened?

Answer (score 0):

`driver.close()` closes the browser window which is currently in focus. If there is more than one window opened, then `driver.close()` will close only the current active window, while the remaining windows will not be closed.

So if you have other windows opened, before loading a new page you first have to  switch to one of them using

```
idx = ... # index of one of your windows
driver.switch_to.window( driver.window_handles[idx] )
```

If there aren't other windows opened, then you have to quit the driver and start a new one.

```
driver.quit()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(...)
```

Comment: driver.close()
 browser = webdriver.Chrome()
 browser.get("https://google.com/")  The above code resolve the issue

Comment: @MuraliRajuNadakuditi If you don't want to use `driver` anymore it is better to run `driver.quit()` which closes it completely

Comment: I'd second that... using quit() should be more reliable especially across different drivers.  I'd also recommend using a sleep in between quit() and launching a new driver if you see any seemingly random exceptions being thrown on startup.  (This gives the browser time to cleanup files/folders used during the 1st session.)

Answer (score 0):

### [driver.close()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#close())

[driver.close()](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#close-window) closes the current top-level browsing context. If there are no more open top-level browsing contexts, then it [closes the session](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-close-the-session).

As `driver.close()` closes only the current top-level browsing context, if there are more top-level browsing context then you need to [switch tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346324/7429447) to any other top-level browsing context.

Else if there are no more top-level browsing context then `driver.close()` closes the session and you have to reinitialize the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) and Browser client. This is equivalent to invoking [`driver.quit()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#quit())

- *Java* snippet:

  ```
  driver.close()
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  ```
- *Python* snippet:

  ```
  driver.close()
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  ```