# Is there any way to open a new tab except send_keys on Selenium Firefox?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I want to open a new tab on Selenium Firefox (on Python 3.6 and MacBook) but the command key does not work to open a new tab. For example,

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
```

This works (moves a page a little down). But the following code does not work.

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "t")
```

, which should open a new tab. Another key such as "q" does not work, either.

So I'm looking for a way to open a new tab (or any other command key combinations) on Selenium and Firefox.

Is there any way except the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

Comment: @Andersson I tried the way the accepted answer explains and found the command key combination is not working, though the down key is. That’s why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

To open a **`New Blank TAB`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('','_blank');")
```

To open a **`New TAB with url`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://facebook.com/');")
```

---

### Update

As per your comment update `execute_script("window.open('','_blank');")` should open a **new TAB** by default. Incase you are seeing different behavior you need to follow the below mentioned steps :

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) level.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v59.0.1*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: Thanks and I did not know there is such way! But actually this opens a new window, not tab.

Comment: @Blaszard Checkout my answer update and let me know the status