# How to open response in a new tab for python flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple code that will generate QR code, But I want the generated QR code to be displayed in a new tab, I already achieved displaying the image in the current page, but I want it to be opened in a new tab instead.

```
  code = form.code.data
  qr = pyqrcode.create(code)
  qr.png(code+'.png', scale=6)
  with open(code+'.png', "rb") as f:
    return Response(f.read(), content_type="image/png")
```

P.S: Edited it for future readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

Comment: Except here he is not using selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this from the client side (the browser / template) as flask runs on the server and has no connection with the browser (client).

From the template you can open a new window, which may or may not open a new tab (it depends on how the user has configured their browser).

Answer (score 0):

If "New tab" means only show on web browser(without downloads),
You can modify below HTTP HEADRS to show image without downloads.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

in flask, you can change http headers by

```
response = flask.Response()
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="filename.png"'
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
```

Comment: Yes, but I think this will still show in the current tab instead of a new tab?