# open 'href' variable in a new tab

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium and chrome webdriver with python.

I'm trying to store 'href' inside a variable ('link' for this example) and open it in a new tab.

i know how to open a dedicated website in a new tab using this way:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.example.com', 'newtab')")
```

but using windows.open script accepts only direct text(as far as i know) and not variables.

**Here is the code:**

```
link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('asset-content').find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='mr-2']").get_attribute("href") #assigning 'href' into link variable. works great. 
driver.execute_script("window.open(link, 'newtab')") #trying to open 'link' in a new tab
```

**The error:**

```
unknown error: link is not defined
```

Any other way i can open 'link' variable in a new tab?

Comment: Note: @Benjamin it's best to provide the entire code so that the error can be reproduced and worked with, as users won't write code to re-produce the error. Otherwise, you'll get a generic solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passing on a string to execute_script, so pass not a 'link' literally, but the value from the link (concatenate):

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('"+link+"','icoTab');")
```

Another way to open a tab is sending CTRL+T to the browser:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
driver.get(link)
```

As mentioned, you can find more here [28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

Comment: Thanks man it worked! "+link+" was the syntax i was missing cause im new to python. i appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the parameter in scripts is not treating as url to make it url try This one. It works for me.

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('{},_blank');".format(link))
```

Please let me know if this work.

Comment: Hi Man, 
'driver.execute_script("window.open('{},_blank');".format(link))' gave me an error but! 
'driver.execute_script("window.open('{});".format(link))' worked!

thanks for teaching me another way to hande this. i appriciate that.

Comment: @Benjamin, The above mentioned code should also work.I don’t know why it’s not working. I have tested and then posted here.Anyways thanks.If it really helps that matters

Comment: another perspective, Nice !