# Open multiple tabs in selenium using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I have generated a list of links using selenium,i need to open each link in a separate tab.I have tried `body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL +"t")`
and `body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND+"t")` but both didn't work(no errors but nothing happens), after searching for answers i found this link [Opening new tabs selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python),however they mostly used java script(which works it opens a new tab) to run it which i can not seem to manipulate such as
`driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://bings.com","_blank");''')` however i can not use this in a for loop as follows:

```
for link in links:
    #driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')")
    driver.execute_script("window.open('%s')")%link
```

Edit [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python): To possible duplicate,the answers given that work are java script codes which works,however i can't use directly in a for loop.

Do i have to open a new random site (using the java script above) then `driver.get(link)` to get to my original link

If it matters i use python 2.7 on Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium multiple tabs at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150593/selenium-multiple-tabs-at-once)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330431/open-href-variable-in-a-new-tab/54331766#54331766

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev please check question again,i clearly state that i know its asked before *however* the answers don't complete the answer i asked,the answers on that "Possible duplicate" simply forces me to open a tab(to a random site) then go to the original link . my question was to open new tab with original link.(Please check that link and my exact question before flagging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `control_string` that you pass as your script:

```
links = ['https://www.yahoo.com', 'http://bings.com']

for link in links:
    control_string = "window.open('{0}')".format(link)
    driver.execute_script(control_string)
```