# Python Selenium Firefox: Unable to open multiple tabs when using Firefox Profiles

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to open multiple tabs within the same browser window in Selenium. I am unable to open multiple tabs if I use a firefox profile. The tabs open normally without the profile. I have searched a lot , but the available answers are opening the tabs as separate windows. What I am after is multiple tabs in the same window in Firefox using a Firefox Profile.

**System Information:**

Windows7
Python 3.7
Firefox 84
Selenium 3.141

I have created a test firefox profile.

**Code with Firefox Profile that doesn't work** - tabs are opened as separate windows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\john\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\0kjv3jas.test')
fp.update_preferences()
first_link = "https://google.com"
second_link = "https://reddit.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities, firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=fp, executable_path='C:\\WebDriver\\bin\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(first_link)
driver.execute_script("window.open('" + second_link +"');")
```

**Code without the Firefox profile works** - create the tabs normally

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
first_link = "https://google.com"
second_link = "https://reddit.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path='C:\\WebDriver\\bin\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(first_link)
driver.execute_script("window.open('" + second_link +"');")
```

References:

[Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)
[Selenium multiple tabs at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150593/selenium-multiple-tabs-at-once)
[Python -- Opening multiple tabs using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281806/python-opening-multiple-tabs-using-selenium)
[Open multiple tabs in selenium using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621313/open-multiple-tabs-in-selenium-using-python)
[Open multiple tabs in selenium using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621313/open-multiple-tabs-in-selenium-using-python)
[Selenium Switch Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690243/selenium-switch-tabs)

https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903
https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/python-selenium-switch-tabs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove firefox profile and it works fine , you are calling an empty profile so you don't need that

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities, firefox_binary=binary,  options=options, executable_path='C:\\WebDriver\\bin\\geckodriver.exe')
```

if you want to use it with profile then use :

```
firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES["frozen"]["browser.link.open_newwindow"] = 3
```

Comment: Thnx, its working after removing the empty profile. If I add a profile, (I have updated the code) then its back to suare one, the tabs open as new window.

Comment: use     fp.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES["frozen"]["browser.link.open_newwindow"] = 3

Comment: awesome that was magic. I had changed the `browser.link.open_newwindow` to 3 in `about:config` but never thought that Selenium copies the profile to a temp `rust`. Thanks for pointing this out, that `browser.link.open_newwindow` is a frozen preference, which means it can't be modified using `profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3)`