# HOW TO OPEN A NEW TAB USING : Selenium?

Tags: python, macos, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

using a MAC OS im trying to open a new tab using selenium firefox webdriver

```
url = "https://google.com" 

mail = wd.Firefox()  

mail.get(url)

 time.sleep(1)

 actions = ActionChains(mail) mail.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/h2/span[2]/span[1]").click() 

time.sleep(1) 

ActionChains(mail).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform()  

mail.close()

 mail.quit()
```

Comment: I hope it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python

Comment: @debanjanb i saw all those post before asking my quiestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are using chrome/firefox you can run this javascript.

```
window.open("https://google.com","_blank")
```

**Python:**

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://google.com','_blank')")
```