# How can I close a tab then go to the other tab with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, window-handles

Here is an example script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.startpage.com/en/')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="query"]').send_keys('Example')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[1]/form/button[2]/span[2]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/section[5]/div[1]/a/h3').click()
```

At the end, it clicks something that opens a new tab. I want to close the new tab and continue working with the original tab

Comment: Isn’t this covered in the docs?

Comment: @AMC most likely, but I can't find it anywhere in the docs

Answer (score 0):

`driver.window_handles` is the object for browser tabs.

Assuming that you want to close second tab (new tab), this works.

```
# continue from your code
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.close()
```

Just change i of `window_handles[i]` for other tab.

Answer (score 0):

To close the new tab and continue working with the original tab you have to:

- Switch to the new tab inducing *WebDriverWait* for `number_of_windows_to_be(2)` and `close()`.
- Switch back to the parent tab.

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

    driver.get('https://www.startpage.com/en/')
    print("Initial Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
    windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
    print("First Window Handle is : %s" %windows_before)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.search-form__input"))).send_keys("Example")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.search-form__button-icon").click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='w-gl__label']//following::h3[1]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
    windows_after = driver.window_handles
    new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
    driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
    print("Page Title after Tab Switching is : %s" %driver.title)
    print("Second Window Handle is : %s" %new_window)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(windows_before)
    print("Page Title after second Tab Switching is : %s" %driver.title)
    print("Current Window Handle is : %s" %windows_before)
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Initial Page Title is : Startpage.com - The world's most private search engine
    First Window Handle is : CDwindow-18CCC5501A5F68CBE1C3094D0D0B419D
    Page Title after Tab Switching is : YouTube
    Second Window Handle is : CDwindow-2EDCAB04A232660E8BCBD7A079DE574B
    Page Title after second Tab Switching is : Startpage.com Search results
    Current Window Handle is : CDwindow-18CCC5501A5F68CBE1C3094D0D0B419D
    ```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python/51893230#51893230)