# Using Selenium to Sign Into TradingView.com

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, window-handles

I'm trying to use Selenium to sign into TradingView, but it appears as though selenium isn't able to find the password field and send keys, though I can see in real time the cursor click into the password field. I've even tried to send keys using ActionChains. I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Below is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def get_data(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/#signin")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Linked In"]').click()
    
    # Switch to new window
    window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
    driver.switch_to.window(window_after)

    # Click into password field, send password
    element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("form__input--floating")[1].click()
    element.send_keys("TestPassword")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

...implies that your program is trying to invoke `click()` on a *`NoneType`* object.

`click()` doesn't returns anything. So `element` remains *`NoneType`* object. Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

To sign into [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/#) website through *linkedin* credentials you have to:

- [Switch to the newly opened window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python/51893230#51893230)
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()`
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/#signin")
  parent_window  = driver.current_window_handle
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Linked In']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  windows_after = driver.window_handles
  new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != parent_window][0]
  driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password']"))).send_keys("BorangeOrange1337")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: tradingview_linkedin_login]

Answer (score 0):

`click` returns None, see source code [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.html#WebElement.click).
Instead of selecting the element, you assign the return code (`None`) to your `element`.

You probably want to first select your element and then in a separate statement `click` on it.

Try the following snippet instead of the last two lines.

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("form__input--floating")[1]
element.click()
element.send_keys("TestPassword")
```

Comment: I get the following error: 
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`