# Send Key Chord to Open New Tab Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have this super simple code I'm trying to run on ChromeDriver but it's not working. The Java equivalent works fine. I want to open a new tab but any working way to send multiple keys would be great.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("t").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python

Comment: @sunilbaba I saw that post before, it didn't work for me. I think something was patched that no longer allows sending multiple keys that way on Chrome. Keys.chord() no longer works for me in Java either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to get your method to work either, I'm not sure why. This did work for me though:

```py
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
```

Comment: Also, after that, run ```driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])``` to interact with the new tab

Comment: What about sending chords in general? What if I want to press ctrl + 1?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think interacting with the pages themselves is fine, but interacting with chrome the browser you should use ```window_handles``` to navigate between them.