# Selenium for Python attach to current session but doesn't load Chrome profile

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I have a script in **Python** that uses **Selenium** to automatically navigate the web.

I'm upgrading my script to make it work even if Chrome has already been opened, **attaching the driver to the current session.**

The code I'm using, which works in part, is:

```
def attach_to_session(executor_url, session_id):
    original_execute = WebDriver.execute
    def new_command_execute(self, command, params=None):
        if command == "newSession":
            # Mock the response
            return {'success': 0, 'value': None, 'sessionId': session_id}
        else:
            return original_execute(self, command, params)
    # Patch the function before creating the driver object
    WebDriver.execute = new_command_execute
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=executor_url, desired_capabilities={})
    driver.session_id = session_id
    # Replace the patched function with original function
    WebDriver.execute = original_execute
    return driver

service = Service('C:\\Users\\nicoc\\PycharmProjects\\WriteAI\\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

executor_url = driver.command_executor._url
session_id = driver.session_id
driver = attach_to_session(executor_url, session_id)
```

It works in part because, it correctly open a new browser window and start navigating according to my code, with an already existing Chrome session open, but **it won't use the Chrome profile the already opened session is using.**

Also, an even better solution would be **to open the driver with a new tab on the already opened Chrome window**, instead of opening a new Chrome Window when launching the driver.

I can still manage that the driver opens a new Chrome window, as soon as it uses the specific profile that it's in use on the active Chrome session.

I have already tried to add the option arguments with

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument\
    (r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\nicoc\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Default')
```

but I got an error saying the profile is already in use

EDIT using the `driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")` while a chrome instance is open returns the error below:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
> argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a
> unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use
> --user-data-dir

if I remove the option

```
chrome_options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\nicoc\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

it opens a new Chrome window but, again, with no profile loaded

Comment: `but I got an error saying the profile is already in use`  - Close the Chrome browser that has been opened and then run the program

Comment: @pmadhu you haven't read the question I guess... The point is to attach the driver to the existing session with that user. As I mention, everything works if I close the browser; I want to launch my script with the browser already opened.

Comment: I did read the the question, but focused on `profile is already in use` part. I am not able to understand. Do you want to open new tabs during automation or open a new URL in the same tab?

Comment: @pmadhu opening a new tab would be best but using an existing tab would also be ok. I just want to attach the driver to the existing Chrome browser which is already open. PS: it's clearly stated in my question: "an even better solution would be to open the driver with a new tab on the already opened Chrome window"

Comment: I have tried to mention the ways to open tabs in the browser. But I am not sure if that is going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To open a new tab you can make use of `JavaScript`:

```
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

# This opens a new tab and loads another URL
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/');")
```

```
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

# This opens a new URL in the same tab
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")
```

To open a browser tab in the existing tab, you can make use of `webbrowser` in python. But I dont think we can automate through that.

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open_new_tab("https://www.linkedin.com/")
```

Links you might want to refer: [Open web in new tab Selenium + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28431765/16452840) https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html

Comment: this solution does not attach to an already existing instance of Chrome. This just opens the driver and opens a new tab. With a Chome instance already open the code returns an error (I already tested). I'm glad and grateful you're trying to help me but, please, try to understand my question first.

Comment: And what is that error?

Comment: user already in use. Updated my question with the error