# How to open multiple web pages in chrome using Selenium Chrome Driver

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium chrome driver to open URLs but when I try to open multiple sites, all are loading in a same tab one by one but I want to open each site in a separate chrome window.

```
IWebDriver driver;
ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
chromeService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
ChromeOptions m_Options = new ChromeOptions();
m_Options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, m_Options);
foreach (var url in urlList)
{
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}
```

Can someone help me to identify the missing piece of code to open each URL in a new window.

Comment: For each url to open in a new window, you need new driver instance for each url. Try keeping the `driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, m_Options);` inside the loop

Comment: This might help if multiple tabs (not windows) works for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42417215/5226491. You'll have to switch to each window for interacting with it, but will work with a single driver instance.

Comment: @AnandGautam - I tired creating new driver instance for each URL, first URL is loading fine but for second URL, tab is opening but web page is not loading. Even I tried with different URL and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In order to open each link in a new, separate tab you will have to open a new tab and switch to that tab before opening the next URL link.
Something like this:

```cs
foreach (var url in urlList)
{
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open();");
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}
```

Be aware that if you are going to open too many windows without closing them this may cause memory lack so that it may case serious problems.