# Can't get an URL from an a href

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrap this website: https://www.sortlist.fr/search

There are lines of websites that can be clicked, and it opens a page for more details of the website.
I want to get that URL, but I can't seem to find it in the <a href

I tried inspecting the element, searching if it was somewhere in a script I couldn't find it.
I tried looping at the network option from the dev tools, also couldn't manage to find it.

Did anyone get any idea?

By the way, I want to use Selenium for this, but there is no login system. So, is it a good idea, or is there a better way?

Comment: There are _**338**_ elements on the https://www.sortlist.fr/search page having href attribute, which one are you looking for?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium as it is a list of websites and I want to get the URL in the href of all of them, I would say every href that lead to a description of the website.
It look like this : https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/pursuit-digital

Comment: This is a react-based web application,  there is a tool you can try named octoparse web scraper.

Comment: @aGreenCoder ok I will take a look at it, but do you think that I can just get the href to be clicked without the need of having the complete URL?

Comment: @Hyaku octopuses web scraper works on the UI level, so yes you can.

Comment: @aGreenCoder Ok I started the scan of the site with it I will se the result when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***agences trouvées*** elements found on the [webpage](https://www.sortlist.fr/search) doesn't contains the *`href`* attribute:

```
<a href="" class="h5 bold text-secondary-900 text-truncate mb-8" data-testid="name-cell">Pursuit Digital</a>
```

So you won't be able to extract the *`href`* attributes from the main page straight away.

---

### Solution

Instead you can click and open the agences trouvées in the [adjascent tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893230/7429447) and print the current URL inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) using the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sortlist.fr/search")
  parent_window = driver.current_window_handle
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-testid='name-cell']")))
  hrefs = []
  for elem in elements:
    elem.click()
    all_windows = driver.window_handles
    new_window = [window for window in all_windows if window != parent_window][0]
    driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
    print(new_window)
    print(driver.current_url)
    hrefs.append(driver.current_url)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(parent_window)
  print(hrefs)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  85F8A3B48F9DF45BEB28D7A530E6979E
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/pursuit-digital
  BA4F926FAD46A5EA5F5FC4406861D20D
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/rozee-digital
  84E3A361C4202C594893546BEF39CD47
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/trends-tokyo
  FC27FFCB9CBE26CD908B8865B8C5CEA5
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/cortlex
  64E50C5041A98BECCB17475A80477D60
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/steinpilz-gmbh
  36FF3D6D3C803BF05EEBB676D58E2DE7
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/everrank-salesdesk24-gmbh
  A13B789C8A618AAD5C372219FC5E3E7E
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/cc-systems
  C39AB3659EE6A627044A2A29CC439AFD
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/snapp-x
  2979C1A6C0FEF21B3499B2184907F28B
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/scrumble
  452F8D30237A146724055715E9690288
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/gaofeng-creative
  F05A9B4963C54306ABBB74420481989E
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/dashdot
  FE2B66F925ACCA122B86E597D28B5403
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/therocketsoft
  FBBE3D1535D35C230A5C7496632435DC
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/run-gun-films
  D4C5C162F3C422FB44862563D8AB73DD
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/studio-unbound
  329DA752A15041450FF5DDAA7850C332
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/contentgo
  B35A03AA6947A1EE043E3EE915E219BE
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/tabua-digital-unipessoal-ldaa
  F77913A1097ACD4DB2B78F4E997B4A0E
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/yarandin-llc
  7A3C75AFF9ED31E5C5E5915A7E9A84EB
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/fortis-media
  C86FCE23AF84B72CFF793A349C005BDD
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/osenorth
  A266A09B3AEDD65E8A43E26DEAECBF22
  https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/apps-square
  ['https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/pursuit-digital', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/rozee-digital', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/trends-tokyo', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/cortlex', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/steinpilz-gmbh', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/everrank-salesdesk24-gmbh', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/cc-systems', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/snapp-x', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/scrumble', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/gaofeng-creative', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/dashdot', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/therocketsoft', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/run-gun-films', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/studio-unbound', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/contentgo', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/tabua-digital-unipessoal-ldaa', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/yarandin-llc', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/fortis-media', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/osenorth', 'https://www.sortlist.fr/agency/apps-square']
  ```