# Opening a new tab in the existing Brave session with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, brave

I'm trying to opening a new tab using Selenium in an existing Brave browser session (so to be able to leverage on some of the cookies previously accepted when normal navigation was carried).

No matter which combination of flags I use, the result is always a new session within the VSCode instance where my code is getting debugged.
I've tried the same with Chrome, but again a new window session is opened with the informative bar suggesting the browser is running via an automated testing platform.

Is there any specific flag/process to attach to an existing session?
The `.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')` that is encountered in several post doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: this has already been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431765/open-web-in-new-tab-selenium-python)

Comment: Thanks, that didn't show up during my researches. I'll give a try and post later more details

Comment: I am reading at the code and it doesn't sound it could achieve what it promises. Already the context manager requires to create an instance of a driver, which will create a new session hence I don't see how I can then move back to another instance of the browser in a different session. Am I missing something?

Comment: So far what I want to achieve doesn't seem to be possible. I can connect to a remote debugging port by using a `options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")` provided an existing browser session has been previously launched (whether at a command line or in a different way) with the `remote-debugging-port=XXXX` to create the communication channel. But connect to a browser session launched with a "standard" desktop icon, no, this does not seem possible at this stage.