# Selenium - cant use keyboard shortcuts

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, keyboard-shortcuts

I have very little experience working with selenium and cant figure out why shortcuts I'm trying to use aren't working. I know that there are multiple ways to do things I'm trying to do eg by executing js snippets, but I'm interested exactly what's wrong with keyboard keys.

*Chrome version:122.0.6261.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)*
*Selenium version 4.18.1*

Code:

This **works correctly** (simple text input):

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://google.com")
    input_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "gLFyf")
    input_element.send_keys("test")
    time.sleep(10)
```

This also **works fine** (inserts "TEST"):

```py
    input_element.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + "test")
```

This **does not work**:

```py
    input_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "gLFyf")
    input_element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "t") # t,j,w,r and other keys
```

This **does not work**

```py
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("t").key_up(
        Keys.CONTROL
    ).perform()
```

This also **does not work**:

```py
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "t")
```

I also tried and it **didn't help**:

1. Changing selenium versions
2. Reinstalling selenium
3. Using different chrome profiles
4. Resetting chrome to default settings

ps Any help is appreciated, I spent hours searching for solution and didn't succeed

Comment: Try it https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/

Comment: As I've mentioned, this does not work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so we can use these shortcuts under selenium to get a new tab or close a tab. (I also dunno why tho)
For specifically opening and closing tabs you can refer this link [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opening-and-closing-tabs-using-selenium/)
For specifically refreshing the page you can use `driver.refresh()`
And history won't be required tbh.

Some of the shortcuts can also be used in selenium like copy and paste. As I had previously stated I don't have any idea why new tab, closing tab and such shortcuts don't work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but there are a lot of mentions that using such shortcuts is the way (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432939/14723492 for example). They also say navigating using TAB also works and is the best solution

Comment: I agree, I had the same issue from my end as you. I was also unable to solve it and used the above solution to solve it. Probably some common issue on our end.